# How to send dynamic parameters with values in struts1.3.8 using hyperlink?

Tags: jsp, parameters, hyperlink, struts

I'm using struts1.3.8. In my JSP page the result will be displayed dynamically.The dynamic result contains hyperlinks. when the user clicks the hyperlink the request should go to Action class along with some dynamic parameters and its values also.
Simple sample code provide for better understanding..
How to implement this????
Response is highly Appreciated
Thanks,
Laxman Chowdary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the JSTL:

```
<a href='<c:url value="someAction.do">
             <c:param name="paramName" value="${someBean.someValue}"/>
         </c:url>'>Click here</a>
```

You can also use the struts [html:link](http://struts.apache.org/1.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3alink) tag, but it's less easy to use than the c:url tag.